# How do I make a clean if statement with multiple clauses?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17

I am tasked to create a little scrabble game and one of my "micro" tasks is computing the score of a given word based on a chart with letter associated with points:

Points Letters

1: a, e, i, l, n, o, r, s, t, u

2: d, g

3: b, c, m, p

4: f, h, v, w, y

5: k

8: j, x

10: q, z

Anyways, My first thought was just looping through the given word and checking each letter with an if loop.

```
for(auto ch: word){
  // as an example this if loop would check if the letter the for loop is on is an 'a' or 'e' or .... 
  // and then adds 1 point to integer 'score' as defined by the bale above
  if(ch == a || ch == e || ch == i || ch == l){
    score = score + 1;
  }
}
```

So my question is, is there a cleaner way of making that if loop?
something like: if(ch == a,e,i,l...) something like that?
For my task I am only allowed to use c++17 but I am fairly new to c++ and am not aware of its fullest potential. Hopefully one of you can tell me what is possible.
Thank you

Comment: use a map of some sort. e.g. std::unordered_map<char, int>. The maps the character to an integer. No need for multiple if conditions just `score += mymap[ch]`.

Comment: Genius! thank you Paul :) I didn't know you could do that with maps! this makes this so much easier

Answer (score 4):

Write a function to compute the value, and implement it with a `switch` statement:

```
Int score(char ch) {
    switch(ch) {
        case ‘a’:
        case ‘e’:
        case ‘i’:
        // etc.
            return 1;
        case ‘d’:
        case ‘g’:
            return 2;
    // and so on …
    }
}
```

The compiler will generate efficient code for this. It will work correctly for any character encoding and is easily extended for richer character sets. It will use far less memory than an `unordered_map` and will almost certainly be faster.

Comment: I think that you should add `[[fallthrough]]`

Comment: `[[fallthrough]]` is only necessary if the case is not empty

Comment: @justANewbie -- the code above is, obviously, a sketch. In your own work, feel free to add all the bells and whistles that you like. I would not clutter code like this with decorations that just say "i mean what the code already says".

Comment: @Mestkon -- `[[fallthrough]]` is never necessary. It has no effect on the validity or the meaning of the code. (Okay, if you've set your compiler to reject valid code based on style guidelines, then you may have to tell it that you want it to ignore those guidelines and just do what the code says)

Comment: This does sound efficient and clean, I will have to read up more on these to figure it out later, but this task does not allow much more than what we have gone through in the course, unfortunately, switch being one of them. Thanks though! (I have much more to learn still)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the characters in the alphabet, you can have an array of the char values, using the character as the offset: (note in this case the mapping is A->J are 1 point, K and L are 2 points etc. You'll have to tweak the mapping for your points.)

```cpp
int point_mapping[] =
{
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  2, 2,
  3, 3, 3, 3,
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
  5,
  8, 8,
  10, 10
};

for (auto& ch : word)
{
    score += point_mapping[tolower(ch) - 'a'];
}
```

Comment: Note that this approach of subtracting 'a' will lock you into languages that only use a-z. For example, it will fail with German scrabble which needs for example ü. The solution in the comment by @Paul Rooney is more general.

Comment: Subtracting `'a'` also won't work when the character encoding puts other characters in the middle of the alphabet. ASCII doesn't do that, but the classic bad-boy of character sets, EBCDIC, does: `'i'` is 0x89, and `'j'` is 0x91; `'r' is 0x99 and `'s'` is 0xA2.

Comment: Interesting I haven't heard of point mapping before. Fortunately, this assignment is English-specific! Thanks for the help